# The Stone-age Limbo People - How do they hunt wild boar?

Tags: internal-consistency, humans, flora, food

The Limbo People (who are hominids with intelligence somewhere between chimpanzees and humans) have long survived by hunting wild boar. They use spears with wooden hafts and flint tips. They are a stone-age people. They don't have fire.

The boars live in the forest which covers the whole world (as far as the Limbo People know) except for the occasional clearing. The undergrowth is thick and the boars run through tunnels they make by eating the plants on which they survive.

The problem for the People is that of getting through this undergrowth. The boars, on four legs, find it easy. The humans find that their best mode of travel is by doing a sort of limbo-dance through the low tunnels.

**Question**

The Limbo People can limbo very quickly but how do they catch and kill the wild boar with only their spears? Limboing forces you to look skyward so how do you see the prey?

**Notes**

Limboing is their normal mode of travel between clearings for all purposes not just hunting.

Crawling belly down does not work because you can't throw a spear from that position.

These people are spear hunters not trappers. They haven't yet invented traps.

They haven't harnessed fire because they live in a rainforest. They eat the boar flesh raw.

Apart from their spears, their only other tools are flint hand knives and hand axes. These are simply chunks of flint that have been split by banging together. They use them to skin the boar and to break into their bones for the marrow.

They can make clearings using their hand axes but it is a very slow job and the undergrowth tends to grow back quickly.

Comment: If you expect your people to survive on pork, they had better have fire.  See e.g. trichinosis.

Answer (score 5):

## This isn't going to end well

Boar are dangerous. Having not had them in the UK for some centuries we've largely forgotten quite how dangerous they are. Boar spears had a crosspiece on them, the reason you were able to spear the boar in the first place because it was charging you, the crosspiece is to stop the boar from running up and gutting you anyway regardless of the spear through its body.

You never take your eyes off a boar until you're absolutely sure it's left the area. If you hunt boar feet first looking upwards, you're going to die.

Boar are omnivorous. They're going to have a lot of Limbo people in their diet.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to throw a spear to hunt with it.

Lay it flat on the ground, the tip facing your target, with a string/rope attached to it. Once the boar will charge you, and it will being a boar, just wait the proper time and lift the tip leaving the other end in the ground.

As soon as the boar hits the tip, its momentum will thrust the spear end in the ground and the tip through its body. Then just get close and finish the job with your axe or another spear.

To implement this tactics you don't need to limbo through the tunnels, just set up and wait.

It would help to shape the head of the spear like a [boar spear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boar_spear), not in metals, of course, but in stone or wood.

> A boar spear is a spear used for boar hunting. It is relatively short and heavy and has two "lugs" or "wings" on the spearsocket behind the blade, which act as a barrier to prevent an injured and furious boar from working its way up the shaft of the spear to attack the hunter.

Comment: Well their normal method of travel for *any* reason is limboing through the tunnels. But I like your idea for the hunting part.

Comment: The problem with this method is that the boar **will not stop charging at you** just because it ran into a spear. That's why [boar spears](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boar_spear) have these vertical "wings", to stop the animal from literally running through the spear and killing the hunter behind it.

Comment: @Elmy, that's why hunting a boar was a matter of pride in the past, while hunting a chicken wasn't...

Answer (score 1):

In tunnels isn't light anyway, so what do you want to see? Darkness?
Thats why, the Limbo People use the spear as blindmans stick and sense them forward until they hear something squeaking in pain. Then they stab repeatedly to hold the boar on distance until it runs out of stamina. Then they pierce forceful to end the preys life. If the boar runs away again, they just follow

Hope it helps...